# Auto voice reply when someone calls you?

Tags: calls, automation, google-voice, google-voice-actions, voicemail

I'm looking for a way to have something reply instantly when the number gets called. Hopefully, the reply will be randomized based on 10< available replies, but any starting point is fine.

I'd rather it be compatible with Messenger and/or Viber, but I understand that it's a hard sell. Also, I've seen Google Voice, but I'm not sure if it can work in this instance? If it could, please help show how